# Highchart with label in custom intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highchart bar graph (column type) which will show the data for each of the dates. Now it is getting the values through AJAX and date range 
can be selected. Because of size limitations, I need to display the date labels in 5 day interval if the date range selected is more than 10 days. 
That is all bars needs to be shown, but the interval for labels should be in 5 days interval if the date range is more than 10 days. If it is 10 days or lower, it should show all the dates.

My graph config is like the following :

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    x: 20,
                    y: 10
                },
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'id_name',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: dates,
                    crosshairs: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Y Axis Title'
                    }
                },
                colors: ['#1A7BB9', '#18A689', '#21B9BB', '#F7A54A', '#EC4758'],
                title: {
                    text: 'My title goes here'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'my subtitle goes here'
                },
                series: PHP formatted data goes here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the interval (every fifth label should be displayed? Or you want to compare time-range to determine that?), but in general you have two solutions:

- **easier one**: disable dataLabels by default (`series.dataLabels.enabled = false`) but enable that for a specific points, for example:

  ```
  series: [{
     data: [{ 
       x: timestamp_1,
       y: timestamp_1,
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: true
       }
     }, [timestamp_2, value_2], [timestamp_3, value_3], ... , {
       x: timestamp_N,
       y: timestamp_N,
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: true
       }
     }]
  }]
  ```
- **harder one**: wrap `drawDataLabels` method, and remove unnecessary labels:

  ```
  (function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function (p) {
      var step = H.pick(this.options.dataLabels.step, 0),
          iterator = 0;

      p.call(this);

      if(step) {
          H.each(this.points, function (point) {
              if (point.dataLabel) {
                  if (iterator % step !== 0) {
                      point.dataLabel = point.dataLabel.destroy();
                  }
                  iterator ++;
              }
          });
      }
    });
  })(Highcharts)
  ```

jsFiddle for the second solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gL2kw73b/2/